# Creating a specific JSON array in C#

Tags: c#, json

I want to create JSON array shown below in C#!

```
questions = [
    {
      question: "What kind of fruit was used to name in 1984?",
      isAnswered: false,
      answers: [
        { id: "1", text: "Blackber123ry", correct: false, userInput: false },
        { id: "2", text: "Blueberry", correct: false, userInput: false },
        { id: "3", text: "Pear", correct: false, userInput: false },
        { id: "4", text: "Apple", correct: true, userInput: false },
      ],
    },
    {
      question: "SECOND QUUESTION",
      isAnswered: false,
      answers: [
        { id: "0", text: "192.168.1.1", correct: false, userInput: false },
        { id: "1", text: "127.0.0.1", correct: true, userInput: false },
        { id: "2", text: "209.85.231.104", correct: false, userInput: false },
        { id: "3", text: "66.220.149.25", correct: false, userInput: false },
      ],
    }];
```

How is that possible? I have idea to create a class with fields **question and isAnswered**
but i don't know how to insert another object array (**answers**)?

Comment: Well, ignore the JSON to start with: how would you *expect* to represent a collection of answers within a `Question` class normally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class/model, you can create a property of type List, assuming Answer is a type you created beforehand with the properties you need (Id, Text, Correct and UserInput).

Here's an exemple according to your Json:

```
public class Model
{
    public List<QuestionModel> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionModel
{
    public string Question { get; set; }

    public bool IsAnswered { get; set; }

    public List<AnswerModel> Answers {get; set; }
}

public class AnswerModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public bool Correct { get; set; }

    public bool UserInput { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to convert a JSON/XML into a C# class is to create a new class. After that, copy your JSON/XML and go to Edit>Past Special > Paste JSON As Classes.

RootObject class

```
namespace TestObject
{
    class RootObject
    {

    }
}
```

Formatted JSON

```
[
   {
      "question":"What kind of fruit was used to name in 1984?",
      "isAnswered":false,
      "answers":[
         {
            "id":"1",
            "text":"Blackber123ry",
            "correct":false,
            "userInput":false
         },
         {
            "id":"2",
            "text":"Blueberry",
            "correct":false,
            "userInput":false
         },
         {
            "id":"3",
            "text":"Pear",
            "correct":false,
            "userInput":false
         },
         {
            "id":"4",
            "text":"Apple",
            "correct":true,
            "userInput":false
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "question":"SECOND QUUESTION",
      "isAnswered":false,
      "answers":[
         {
            "id":"0",
            "text":"192.168.1.1",
            "correct":false,
            "userInput":false
         },
         {
            "id":"1",
            "text":"127.0.0.1",
            "correct":true,
            "userInput":false
         },
         {
            "id":"2",
            "text":"209.85.231.104",
            "correct":false,
            "userInput":false
         },
         {
            "id":"3",
            "text":"66.220.149.25",
            "correct":false,
            "userInput":false
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Copy JSON and go to Edit>Past Special > Paste JSON As Classes

```
namespace TestObject
{
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public string question { get; set; }
        public bool isAnswered { get; set; }
        public Answer[] answers { get; set; }
    }

    public class Answer
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public bool correct { get; set; }
        public bool userInput { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Rename the class and property with your need

```
namespace TestObject
{
    public class RootObject
    {
        public Questions[] questions{ get; set; }
    }

    public class Questions
    {
        public string question { get; set; }
        public bool isAnswered { get; set; }
        public Answer[] answers { get; set; }
    }

    public class Answer
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public bool correct { get; set; }
        public bool userInput { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what i do is use an online json-to-c# converter. if i put your json there, i get the below structure

```
public class Answer
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public bool correct { get; set; }
    public bool userInput { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public string question { get; set; }
    public bool isAnswered { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> answers { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Question> questions { get; set; }
}
```